# Get UV texture coords for XYZ point 3d models

Tags: 3d, textures, uv-mapping

I writing self base opengl realisation (scanline, light model), but I have a problem.
I have .obj model with UV texture coords for all vertices, but I haven't any through, how I cat get UV texture coords by XYZ model.

Comment: You interpolate the vertex UV coordinates within the surfaces you’re drawing

Comment: How I can do it?